# Why is D3.js panning is slower than zooming when there are many (thousands) SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

D3.js panning appears to be slower and more choppy than zooming when the svg has many elements. I made an example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cornhundred/cfeu1ws2/10/ and the code is also shown below

```
var num_rect = 3000;

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
    console.log('zooming or panning');
    d3.select('svg')
        .select('#rect_group')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 800)
    .call(zoom);

var rect_group = d3.select('svg')
    .append('g')
    .attr('id', 'rect_group');

var data = _.range(num_rect);

var color = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, num_rect]).range(['red', 'blue']);

rect_group.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('height', 175)
    .attr('width', 5)
    .attr('x', function (d) {return 50 + d / (0.003 * num_rect);})
    .attr('y', 50)
    .style('fill', function (d) {return color(d);});
```

In this example I'm appending `num_rects` rectangles onto the svg side-by-side and adding some coloring so its clear there are many rectangles. I'm also making a console log whenever the zoomed function is called.

Increasing `num_rect` above ~3000 caused panning to be choppy while zooming remained smooth. This can ben seen in the behavior of the visualization or from the frequency of the console logs - 'zooming or panning'. This is odd since I would expect panning to be as cpu intensive than zooming.

This behavior also appears to be browser-specific - I'm only seeing this in chrome (which is also odd since Chrome is usually the best at rendering D3.js visualizations).

Comment: It's more work for the browser to render all the elements.

Comment: But is there any reason that panning would behave differently than zooming?

Comment: Panning redraws the elements at each pixel step whereas zooming works with discrete levels that you normally don't interpolate between.

Comment: I've also noticed that splitting the rects into separate groups improves panning speed in Chrome - see http://jsfiddle.net/cornhundred/cfeu1ws2/10/ . I would have expected that adding more svg components would slow panning down.

Comment: Performance is really hard to predict as rendering engines apply optimisations and similar things.

Comment: Thanks for the info ... the link in the above comment should have been http://jsfiddle.net/cornhundred/gg6328ab/2/