# Can I add optional URL description after final slash using Flask with a variable in the URL?

Tags: python, flask

I want to pass an optional description after the last slash in a URL using Flask - like what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424271/why-is-d3-js-panning-is-slower-than-zooming-when-there-are-many-thousands-sv)

where the description, "why-...", is optional.

I am also passing a variable to the 'something' route after the last slash

```
@app.route("/something/<variable>")
def something(variable):
  ...
```

I can get something similar working if I pass the optional description after some other character (using ":" for instance) and just strip off the description

```
@app.route("/something/<variable>")
def something(variable):
  variable = variable.split(':')[0]
  ...
```

But I'm wondering if the same can be done using a forward slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a second route that takes the extra parameter.  Give the parameter a default value.  Ignore the parameter.

```
@app.route('/questions/<int:id>')
@app.route('/questions/<int:id>/<slug>')
def question(id, slug=None):
    ...
```